# Magento - How to check what discount a product will get if placed in the cart

Tags: magento

I would like to get Magento to tell me any discounts that a product would get if placed in the cart. What is the best way to do this? Are there any models or helpers to which I can pass a product and it returns the discount amount?

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented something similar in Shipping Estimator extension. There is few options available for you:

1. Create a temporary quote object, add product to it, recalculate totals and check quote item's discounts.
2. Use existing quote object that is used by customer and add product to it as well. But in this case all discount rules will be applied including products that are already in cart.

Here is an example of code that is used for [shipping estimator](https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_ProductPageShipping):

```
    $request = new Varien_Object($addToCartInfo);

    if ($product->getStockItem()) {
        $minimumQty = $product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
        if($minimumQty > 0 && $request->getQty() < $minimumQty){
            $request->setQty($minimumQty);
        }
    }

    $result = $quote->addProduct($product, $request);

    if (is_string($result)) {
        Mage::throwException($result);
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after',
                        array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));

    $quote->collectTotals();
    $result = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

As I told before quote can be initialized in two different ways:

1. New Quote:

   ```
   $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
   ```
2. Existing Customer Quote:

   ```
   $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
   ```

As for discount retrieval from quote item, it will be your homework :)

Comment: There's downsides to both of those options.  1) you waste a quote_id. Probably not a big deal unless you have a high volume site.  2) you run the risk of the item being left in the customer's cart when they hadn't intended to add it. Could cause customer service issues.

Comment: Just to add to this it important to specify addresses to the quote otherwise the address object collect totals would not be invoked and thus discounts would not be calculated :) ... homework done :P

Comment: @JoeConstant, there is no need to SAVE quote, so quote id is not wasted :)